# Aurelia Child Router with href

Tags: aurelia

There are many similiar questions, and I have read them all.  But still, I cannot get this to work correctly.

Main router works fine:

```
{ route: [''], name: 'defaultRoute', moduleId: 'pages/entity/entity-router' }
```

Child Router:

```
configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {
        config.map([
            { route: [''], name: 'home', moduleId: 'pages/entity/home' },
            { route: ['entityDetails/:id'], name: 'entityDetails', moduleId: 'pages/entity/entity-details' }
        ]);

        this.router = router;
    }
```

The home page shows up just fine and shows a list which the user then clicks on.  I want the list to stay in place, and the details section gets updated by the navigation.

The difficulty is is navigating to the entityDetails page with an href:

```
<a route-href="route: entityDetails; params.bind: { id: item.id }">${item.name}</a>
```

The link that is created looks like this:  `/entityDetails/8`

The link that works if I type it in the address bar is: "#/home/entityDetails/8"

So it looks on the Main router for this route, but it is not found.

As a test, I put the route on the Main Router, and it then does find it.

How do I make it so it find the route on the child router?

Comment: Are you injecting the router, or creating a new instance? Have you tried generating the href in code, like: `this.router.generate( "entityDetails", { id: item.id });` ?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not supported yet. Look https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/89. However, you could use `this.router.parent.generate('')` to generate part of the route and then concatenate with `this.router.generate('')`

Comment: @FabioLuz, ok, I thought maybe I was doing something wrong. If you want to post as an answer, I will accept.